# Spring Cloud DataFlow automated run

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want my application to run DataFlow task after some condition is satisfied (some event raises). 
Is there any way to run that from code:

1. Some event raised
2. Spring DataFlow starts some task

without Spring DataFlow shell, just start all from my code (register app in DataFlow, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of ["stream-launching-a-task"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-launch-tasks-from-stream) feature to automate the launching of any arbitrary short-lived task application.

SCDF also offers [REST-API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide) and an [REST-template](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dataflow-template) that can be used for programmatic orchestration as opposed to the DSL/Shell.

Check out this [example orchestration](https://github.com/kbastani/event-stream-processing-microservices/blob/master/platform-services/data-flow-server/src/main/java/demo/ImportResources.java#L77) for mode details

Comment: Thanks a lot! REST APi is exactly what I need!